# How to get subgraph S comprised of nodes with multiple edges of a multigraph M?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a graph M, I would like to get the subgraph S which contains only the nodes of M which have two or more edges. I am mainly looking to see if there is an already-known algorithm which does this.

For anyone looking at this question in the future or confused by this question, my graph could be represented by a dictionary like so, where each key is a node and the value is how many edges connect the nodes:

```
{
A: {B: 2, C: 1, D: 3}
B: {A: 2, D: 2}
C: {A: 1}
D: {A: 3, B: 2, E: 1}
E: {D: 1}
}
```

The subgraph I would like to get is:

```
{
A: {B: 2, D: 3}
B: {A: 2, D: 2}
D: {A: 3, B: 2}
}
```

Comment: Clarifying question: Are you looking for the subgraph induced by the nodes of degree at least $2$ in the original graph, or are you looking for the largest subgraph that has minimum degree $2$(if it exists)?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that well versed in graph theory. I am looking for the graph which contains all nodes that have degree greater than one. So all nodes of degree one will not be in the subgraph.

Comment: So if the algorithm was given a path, would it return a path with two less vertices, or would it say there are no subgraphs with the desired property?

Comment: If the algorithm was given two nodes with one edge between them, it would say there are no subgraphs with the desired property. If it was given two nodes with two edges between them, it would return the same graph it was given.

Comment: That does not address my question. If the algorithm was given a graph on three vertices, A, B and C with a single edge between A and B, and a single edge between B and C, would the algorithm return a single vertex(namely B) or would the algorithm say there are no desired subgraphs?

Comment: No desired subgraphs because every vertex must have a degree of at least two. Sorry, was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it sounds like, you are looking for an algorithm to find the $2$-core of a graph. The $k$-core of a graph is the (unique) maximal subgraph that had minimum degree $k$. There are algorithms to find the $k$-core of a graph. For more information about cores and the algorithms to find them, here is the wikipedia entry that discusses $k$-cores and includes an algorithm to find the $k$-core: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)